# Generic type having the special constructor and calling it

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a few classes class and all they `extend Response(response)`, that is to say, have the same constructor:

```
import scalaj.http.Http

class MyClass1(response: Http.Request) extends Response(response) { 
  //....
}

class MyClass2(response: Http.Request) extends Response(response) { 
  //....
}
```

How do I create a generic method which accepts only a type of the classes above and call its constructor:

```
def myGeneric[A <: ???](r: Http.Request)  = {
  new A(r) // doesn't compile
}
```

I'd like to call it like this:

```
myGeneric[MyClass1](r) // r is Http.Request
```

I can do this:

```
def myGeneric[A <: ???](r: Http.Request)(f: r => A)  = {
  f(r) // f - is the constructor
}

myGeneric[MyClass1](r) { x =>
  new MyClass1(x)
}
```

But is there more elegant way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make `myGeneric` take a factory as the implicit parameter.  For example:

```
def myGeneric[A](r: Request)(implicit f: Request => A) {
  ...  val a = f(r)  ...
```

If I remember right, bare implicit functions like that can get confusing, so maybe ...

```
trait MyFactory[T] {
    def make(r: Request): T
}
...
def myGeneric[A](r: Request)(implicit f: MyFactory[A]) ...
// which is same as...
def myGeneric[A : MyFactory](r: Request) ...
```